# How to make use of multithread feature of Eigenvalues in ParallelDo or ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization, mkl

In mathematica, `Eigenvalues` is implemented internally using intel MKL.

When running

```
Eigenvalues[RandomReal[1.,{2000,2000}]
```

you will notice mathematica uses all available threads predefined in

```
SystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber"]
```

However, if we use `Eigenvalues` in `ParallelDo` or `ParallelTable`

```
ParallelDo[Eigenvalues[RandomReal[1.,{2000,2000}],{1}]
```

the Threading feature of MKL automatically disabled.

How to avoid this? It is important, since I am working with very large matrices, and my cluster node has 24 cores. I have 6 tasks to do, I want to parallelize them, and each use 4 threads, so all the resources can be utilized. And what is more, can mathematica like MPI. In MPI when calling MKL threaded functions, MPI automatically, dynamically and evenly distribute all threads to different MPI processes. Is it possible in Mathematica?

Comment: As an alternative if nothing else works, can you package your calculation as .m script files that you can run from shell, or even invoke from inside a ParallelDo?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Of course, on a cluster, I have to pack my calculation as .m file. But what do you mean invoke inside ParallelDo?

Comment: I mean something dirty like `ParallelDo[Run["! MathKernel -script "<>filename[index], {index, indexRange}]`.

Comment: Set `"MKLThreadNumber"` on the subkernels.

Comment: @ilian, perhaps you could post this as an answer?

Comment: @ilian Thanks! I forgot this trick! `ParallelEvaluate@SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions"->"MKLThreadNumber"->4]` works. However, is it possible to make the thread distribution dynamic? I mean when one of the parallel tasks is done, the available threads can distributed to the running tasks. I tried setting `MKLThreadNumber"->24` at first, but it harms the whole performance.

Comment: I don't think it's possible within *Mathematica*, though with the default setting of `MKL_DYNAMIC`, MKL will itself take care of using fewer threads when necessary.

Comment: @ilian Where is `MKL_DYNAMIC`? If it is the default setting, why `ParallelDo` disable it?