# Cuba Integrator can't perform parallelization

Tags: numerical-integration

I was using `Cuba` library to do some integration, but I found that it's generally much slower with parallelization than without.

**MWE:**

```
Install["/path/to/Cuba/Vegas"];
SetOptions[Vegas,Verbose->0];
Vegas[Sin[x],{x,0,1},PrecisionGoal->6,MaxPoints->10^6]//AbsoluteTiming
(*{8.48996, {{0.4597, 0.0000217312, 4.32426*10^-14 }}}*)
MapSample = ParallelMap;
Vegas[Sin[x],{x,0,1},PrecisionGoal->6,MaxPoints->10^6]//AbsoluteTiming
(*{55.2991, {{0.4597, 0.0000217312, 4.32426*10^-14 }}}*)
```

We can see that parallelization (with 16 kernels) is 7 times slower than without parallelization. If I increase the number of kernels to 32, the speed is even slower (102s).

**EDIT:**

The tests performed above is on a workstation with E5-2680 v3 (48 threads) and I tried both MMA 11.3 and 12.1. I also tested it on a PC with a i7-4790 (only opened 6 kernels) and the MMA version is 12.1. Cuba in question is Cuba-4.2.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the specs of the rest of the system...often the bottleneck is something else.

Comment: @morbo I added some infos. Hope it helps.

Comment: My guess that the MKL is multi-threaded, but `ParallelMap` sets the maximum number of threads to `1` (one), and you lose the efficiency of the MKL, if the Cuba package is written to take advantage of it. The advice [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51363/4999) and in the comments [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113490/4999) may be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Manually setting MKLThreadNumber to 4 in parallel kernels didn't help.